# Is there a way to combine a start and endtime column to a single datetime column within R (with grouped data)

Tags: r, dplyr, coalesce

I have a dataset that contains the following columns:

starttime, endtime and ID

Is there a way to combine the starttime and endtime to a single datetime column whilst grouping by ID?

For example, I have this:

```
            StartTime                Endtime                ID

          12/18/2019 5:20:23 AM 12/18/2019 5:20:24 AM       A
          12/18/2019 2:01:40 PM 12/18/2019 2:01:47 PM       A
```

I would like this:

```
          DateTimeUTC                                      ID

          12/18/2019 5:20:23 AM                             A
          12/18/2019 5:20:24 AM                             A
          12/18/2019 2:01:40 PM                             A
          12/18/2019 2:01:47 PM                             A
```

I have tried this:

```
library(dplyr)

data %>%  group_by(ID) %>%  coalesce(Starttime, Endtime)
```

This command yields an error. I will further research this. Any help is appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `pivot_longer` from `tidyr` reshape the data into 'long' format.  `coalesce` is used when there are multiple columns with missing values (`NA`) and want to merge into a single column which returns the first non-NA column value in each row (if there are no non-NA, it returns NA)

```
 library(dplyr)
 library(tidyr)
 data %>%
     pivot_longer(cols = -ID, values_to = "DateTimeUTC") %>%
     select(DateTimeUTC, ID)
# A tibble: 4 x 2
#  DateTimeUTC           ID   
#  <chr>                 <chr>
#1 12/18/2019 5:20:23 AM A    
#2 12/18/2019 5:20:24 AM A    
#3 12/18/2019 2:01:40 PM A    
#4 12/18/2019 2:01:47 PM A
```

#### data

```
data <- structure(list(StartTime = c("12/18/2019 5:20:23 AM", "12/18/2019 2:01:40 PM"
), Endtime = c("12/18/2019 5:20:24 AM", "12/18/2019 2:01:47 PM"
), ID = c("A", "A")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))
```